# SVD of an orthogonal projector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, svd, orthogonal-matrices, projection-matrices

Here is my observation:

> Suppose there is an orthogonal projector $P$ such that $P=P^2$. 
> Then for arbitrary $x$, $Px$ and $(I-P)x$ are orthogonal. 
> So we have
> $$ x^* P^* (I-P)x=0$$
> where $A^*$ means a transpose of $A$.
> Since $x$ is arbitrary, it implies
> $$ P^*(I-P)=P^*-P^*P=0$$
> Note that substituting $x=I$ yields the same result. 
> Now suppose that $P$ has SVD $P=USV^*$ where $U$, $V$ are unitary and $S$ is a positive diagonal matrix.
> Then
> $$P^*= VSU^*=VSU^*USV^*=VS^2V^*=P^*P$$
> Now by multiplying $S^{-1}V^*$ to the left of both sides,
> $$U^*=SV^*$$
> and by multiplying $U$ to the left of both sides,
> $$I=USV^*=P$$
> which is not obviously true.

I think my proof has a critical error, but I could not find it.
Would you give me an advice?
Thanks.

Comment: An orthogonal projection is symmetric.  Therefore, the spectral theorem gives you a decomposition $P = U^{*} \Sigma U$ directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the step where you "multiply $S^{-1}V^*$ to the left of both sides". If $S$ is invertible, then that implies that $P = USV^*$ is invertible. However, if a projector $P$ is invertible, then we have
$$
P^2 = P \implies P^{-1}P^2 = P^{-1}P \implies P = I,
$$
which was the conclusion that you reached. If $P$ is a projector with $P \neq I$, then it must hold that $P$ is singular.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Then can we prove the statement 'if $P$ is orthogonal then $U=V$' starting from $SU^*=S^2V^*$?

Comment: @okw1124 We can't prove that statement because the statement is not true. As an example, consider the SVD $P =  USV^*$ where
$$
P = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}, \quad U = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1}, \quad S = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}, \quad V = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}.
$$